# My Php Script Error

Tags: php, phpbb3

i have a script named remauth.php
it connects to phpbb database and use some information of users.
its code:

```
<?php
// standard phpBB setup
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "94.23.147.71" || $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "188.226.149.35")
{
    unset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REAL_IP'];
}

if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == "94.23.147.71" || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == "188.226.149.35")
{
    unset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
}

function get_ip_address()
{
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true)
        {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip)
            {
                if ($_SERVER[$key] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER[$key] == "94.23.147.71" || $_SERVER[$key] == "188.226.149.35")
                {
                    unset($_SERVER[$key]);
                }

                if (valid_ip($ip) !== false)
                {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

get_ip_address();
$acm_type = "memcache";
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
define('IN_CHECK_BAN', 1);
define('IN_LOGIN', 1);
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
//include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_profile_fields.' . $phpEx);

if (!function_exists('group_memberships'))
{
    include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.'.$phpEx);
}

function valid_ip($ip)
{
    return (!preg_match( "/^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/", $ip)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$canPlay = false;

function isGroup($userid)
{
    $groups = group_memberships(false, $userid);
    $return = false;

    foreach ($groups as $grouprec)
    {
        if ($grouprec['group_id'] == 2 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 3 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 4 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 5 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 8 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 9 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 10)
        {
            $return = true;
        }
    }  

    return $return;
}

function get_profile_fields($user_id)
{
    global $db;

    $sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM ' . PROFILE_FIELDS_DATA_TABLE . '
        WHERE ' . $db->sql_in_set('user_id', array_map('intval', $user_id));
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

    $field_data = array();

    while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
    {
        $field_data[$row['user_id']] = $row;
    }

    $db->sql_freeresult($result);
    $user_fields = array();
    $fields = array('can_has_servers', 'can_play', 'can_play_expire', 'can_play_reason');

    foreach ($fields as $used_ident)
    {
        foreach ($field_data as $user_id => $row)
        {
            $user_fields[$user_id][$used_ident]['value'] = $row['pf_' . $used_ident];
        }
    }

    return $user_fields;
}

function check_ban($user_id = false, $user_ips = false, $user_email = false, $return = false)
{
    global $config, $db;

    $banned = false;
    $cache_ttl = 3600;
    $where_sql = array();

    $sql = 'SELECT ban_ip, ban_userid, ban_email, ban_exclude, ban_give_reason, ban_end
            FROM ' . BANLIST_TABLE . '
            WHERE ';

    // determine which entries to check, only return those
    if ($user_email === false)
    {
        $where_sql[] = "ban_email = ''";
    }

    if ($user_ips === false)
    {
        $where_sql[] = "(ban_ip = '' OR ban_exclude = 1)";
    }

    if ($user_id === false)
    {
        $where_sql[] = '(ban_userid = 0 OR ban_exclude = 1)';
    }
    else
    {
        $cache_ttl = ($user_id == ANONYMOUS) ? 3600 : 0;
        $_sql = '(ban_userid = ' . $user_id;

    if ($user_email !== false)
    {
        $_sql .= " OR ban_email <> ''";
    }

    if ($user_ips !== false)
    {
        $_sql .= " OR ban_ip <> ''";
    }

        $_sql .= ')';

        $where_sql[] = $_sql;
    }

    $sql .= (sizeof($where_sql)) ? implode(' AND ', $where_sql) : '';
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql, $cache_ttl);

    $ban_triggered_by = 'user';
    while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
    {
        if ($row['ban_end'] && $row['ban_end'] < time())
        {
            continue;
        }

        $ip_banned = false;
        if (!empty($row['ban_ip']))
        {
            if (!is_array($user_ips))
            {
                $ip_banned = preg_match('#^' . str_replace('\*', '.*?', preg_quote($row['ban_ip'], '#')) . '$#i', $user_ips);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($user_ips as $user_ip)
                {
                    if (preg_match('#^' . str_replace('\*', '.*?', preg_quote($row['ban_ip'], '#')) . '$#i', $user_ip))
                    {
                        $ip_banned = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ((!empty($row['ban_userid']) && intval($row['ban_userid']) == $user_id) ||
            $ip_banned ||
            (!empty($row['ban_email']) && preg_match('#^' . str_replace('\*', '.*?', preg_quote($row['ban_email'], '#')) . '$#i', $user_email)))
        {
            if (!empty($row['ban_exclude']))
            {
                $banned = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $banned = true;
                $ban_row = $row;

                if (!empty($row['ban_userid']) && intval($row['ban_userid']) == $user_id)
                {
                    $ban_triggered_by = 'user';
                }
                else if ($ip_banned)
                {
                    $ban_triggered_by = 'ip';
                }
                else
                {
                    $ban_triggered_by = 'email';
                }

                // don't break. Check if there is an exclude rule for this user
            }
        }
    }

    $db->sql_freeresult($result);

    if ($banned && !$return)
    {
        global $template;

        // if the session is empty we need to create a valid one...
        if (empty($this->session_id))
        {
            // this seems to be no longer needed? - #14971
            //$this->session_create(ANONYMOUS);
        }

        // initiate environment ... since it won't be set at this stage
        $this->setup();

        // logout the user, banned users are unable to use the normal 'logout' link
        if ($this->data['user_id'] != ANONYMOUS)
        {
            $this->session_kill();
        }

        // we show a login box here to allow founders accessing the board if banned by IP
        if (defined('IN_LOGIN') && $this->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)
        {
            global $phpEx;

            $this->setup('ucp');
            $this->data['is_registered'] = $this->data['is_bot'] = false;

            // Set as a precaution to allow login_box() handling this case correctly as well as this function not being executed again.
            define('IN_CHECK_BAN', 1);

            login_box("index.$phpEx");

            // The false here is needed, else the user is able to circumvent the ban.
            $this->session_kill(false);
        }

        // ok, we catch the case of an empty session id for the anonymous user...
        // this can happen if the user is logging in, banned by username and the login_box() being called "again".
        if (empty($this->session_id) && defined('IN_CHECK_BAN'))
        {
            $this->session_create(ANONYMOUS);
        }

        // determine which message to output
        $till_date = ($ban_row['ban_end']) ? $this->format_date($ban_row['ban_end']) : '';
        $message = ($ban_row['ban_end']) ? 'BOARD_BAN_TIME' : 'BOARD_BAN_PERM';

        $message = sprintf($this->lang[$message], $till_date, '<a href="mailto:' . $config['board_contact'] . '">', '</a>');
        $message .= ($ban_row['ban_give_reason']) ? '<br /><br />' . sprintf($this->lang['BOARD_BAN_REASON'], $ban_row['ban_give_reason']) : '';
        $message .= '<br /><br /><em>' . $this->lang['BAN_TRIGGERED_BY_' . strtoupper($ban_triggered_by)] . '</em>';

        // to circumvent session_begin returning a valid value and the check_ban() not called on second page view, we kill the session again
        $this->session_kill(false);

        // a very special case... we are within the cron script which is not supposed to print out the ban message... show blank page
        if (defined('IN_CRON'))
        {
            garbage_collection();
            exit_handler();
            exit;
        }

        trigger_error($message);
    }

    return ($banned && $ban_row['ban_give_reason']) ? $ban_row['ban_give_reason'] : $banned;
}

// session stuff will not be needed as this occurs from a non-client session, but we need $user->setup it seems
if (empty($user->lang))
{
    $user->setup();
}

$user->add_lang('ucp');

// get variables
/* $data = request_var('data', '', true);
if (!isset($_GET['username']))
{ */
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = explode('&&', $data);

    $username = trim(htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\0"), array("\n", "\n", ''), $data[0]), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
    $password = trim(htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\0"), array("\n", "\n", ''), $data[1]), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
/* }
else
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];    
} */

// perform login from $auth. we don't want autologon, viewonline nor admin access for the session
$result = $auth->login($username, $password, false, false, false);
if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
{
    $userID = $user->data['user_id'];
    $user_id = array($userID);
    $canhave = get_profile_fields($user_id);

    if ($canhave[$userID]['can_play_expire']['value'] <= time())
    {
        $canhave[$userID]['can_play']['value'] = 1;
    }

    if ($canhave[$userID]['can_play']['value'] == 1 || $canhave[$userID]['can_play']['value'] == 0 || $canhave[$userID]['can_play']['value'] == "")
    {
        $canPlay = true;

        if (true || isGroup($user->data['user_id'])) 
        {
            $canPlay = true; 
            $keysql = "UPDATE phpbb_sessions SET session_onlineplay = 1, session_realip = '".htmlspecialchars(get_ip_address(), ENT_QUOTES)."' WHERE session_id = '".$user->session_id."';";
            $keyresult = $db->sql_query($keysql); 
            $db->sql_freeresult($keyresult);
        }
        else
        {
            $result['status'] = 'nope';  
            $result['error_msg'] = 'triobit is currently down for maintenance.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result['status'] = 'nope';  
        //$result['error_msg'] = 'User is not allowed to play'; 
        $result['error_msg'] = 'Online playing privileges revoked';

        if ($canhave[$userID]['can_play_reason']['value'])
        {
            $result['error_msg'] .= ' - ' . str_replace('#', '@', $canhave[$userID]['can_play_reason']['value']);
        }

        if ($canhave[$userID]['can_play_expire']['value'])
        {
            $result['error_msg'] .= ' (will expire in ' . duration($canhave[$userID]['can_play_expire']['value'] - time()) . ')';
        }
    }

    $banReason = check_ban($userID, '', '', 1);
    if ($banReason != "")
    {
        $result['status'] = 'nope';  
        $result['error_msg'] = 'User is banned';   
        $canPlay = false;
    } 
}

// start buffering (to allow kill)
ob_start();

// output the results
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? 'ok' : 'fail') . '#';
echo (($result['error_msg']) ? ((isset($user->lang[$result['error_msg']])) ? $user->lang[$result['error_msg']] : $result['error_msg']) : 'Success.') . '#';
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? $user->data['user_id'] : '1') . '#';
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? $user->data['username'] : 'Anonymous') . '#';
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? $user->data['user_email'] : 'anonymous@example.com') . '#';
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? $user->session_id : '0') . '#';

//Deleted, used for login verify now
// kill the session
if (!$canPlay)
{
    $user->session_kill(false);
}

// and flush the contents
ob_end_flush();
exit;

function format_duration($seconds) {
    $periods = array(
        'centuries' => 3155692600,
        'decades' => 315569260,
        'years' => 31556926,
        'months' => 2629743,
        'weeks' => 604800,
        'days' => 86400,
        'hours' => 3600,
        'minutes' => 60,
        'seconds' => 1
    );

    $durations = array();

    foreach ($periods as $period => $seconds_in_period) {
        if ($seconds >= $seconds_in_period) {
            $durations[$period] = floor($seconds / $seconds_in_period);
            $seconds -= $durations[$period] * $seconds_in_period;
        }
    }

    return $durations;
}

function duration($seconds) {
    $data = format_duration($seconds);
    $data2 = array();

    foreach ($data as $unit => $amount)
    {
        $data2[] = $amount . ' ' . $unit;
    }

    return implode(', ', $data2);
}
?>
```

and its error

> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in C:\xnp\htdocs\remauth.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in C:\xnp\htdocs\remauth.php on line 9
>
> Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in C:\xnp\htdocs\remauth.php on line 9

help me please.

Comment: If you dump $_SERVER variable does it have HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR in it ?

Comment: What is **line 9** of `C:\xnp\htdocs\remauth.php`?

Comment: Use `isset()` to check if it exists

Comment: its line 9:if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == "94.23.147.71" || $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] == "188.226.149.35")
{
    unset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']);
}

Comment: So it is simply not set in _SERVER and the IP is found in the REMOTE_ADDR field. As already mentioned check the existence by `isset()` first. Since it is only a notice, it is no big problem. Btw. display_errors should be turned off on productive systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use HTTP_HOST instead of HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR**

```
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "94.23.147.71" || $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == "188.226.149.35")
{
    unset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
}

function get_ip_address()
{
    foreach (array('HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_HOST', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', 'REMOTE_ADDR') as $key)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true)
        {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip)
            {
                if ($_SERVER[$key] == "127.0.0.1" || $_SERVER[$key] == "94.23.147.71" || $_SERVER[$key] == "188.226.149.35")
                {
                    unset($_SERVER[$key]);
                }

                if (valid_ip($ip) !== false)
                {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

get_ip_address();
$acm_type = "memcache";
$phpbb_root_path = (defined('PHPBB_ROOT_PATH')) ? PHPBB_ROOT_PATH : './';
define('IN_PHPBB', true);
define('IN_CHECK_BAN', 1);
define('IN_LOGIN', 1);
$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);
include($phpbb_root_path . 'common.' . $phpEx);
//include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_profile_fields.' . $phpEx);

if (!function_exists('group_memberships'))
{
    include_once($phpbb_root_path . 'includes/functions_user.'.$phpEx);
}

function valid_ip($ip)
{
    return (!preg_match( "/^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$/", $ip)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
}

$user->session_begin();
$auth->acl($user->data);
$canPlay = false;

function isGroup($userid)
{
    $groups = group_memberships(false, $userid);
    $return = false;

    foreach ($groups as $grouprec)
    {
        if ($grouprec['group_id'] == 2 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 3 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 4 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 5 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 8 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 9 || $grouprec['group_id'] == 10)
        {
            $return = true;
        }
    }  

    return $return;
}

function get_profile_fields($user_id)
{
    global $db;

    $sql = 'SELECT *
        FROM ' . PROFILE_FIELDS_DATA_TABLE . '
        WHERE ' . $db->sql_in_set('user_id', array_map('intval', $user_id));
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql);

    $field_data = array();

    while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
    {
        $field_data[$row['user_id']] = $row;
    }

    $db->sql_freeresult($result);
    $user_fields = array();
    $fields = array('can_has_servers', 'can_play', 'can_play_expire', 'can_play_reason');

    foreach ($fields as $used_ident)
    {
        foreach ($field_data as $user_id => $row)
        {
            $user_fields[$user_id][$used_ident]['value'] = $row['pf_' . $used_ident];
        }
    }

    return $user_fields;
}

function check_ban($user_id = false, $user_ips = false, $user_email = false, $return = false)
{
    global $config, $db;

    $banned = false;
    $cache_ttl = 3600;
    $where_sql = array();

    $sql = 'SELECT ban_ip, ban_userid, ban_email, ban_exclude, ban_give_reason, ban_end
            FROM ' . BANLIST_TABLE . '
            WHERE ';

    // determine which entries to check, only return those
    if ($user_email === false)
    {
        $where_sql[] = "ban_email = ''";
    }

    if ($user_ips === false)
    {
        $where_sql[] = "(ban_ip = '' OR ban_exclude = 1)";
    }

    if ($user_id === false)
    {
        $where_sql[] = '(ban_userid = 0 OR ban_exclude = 1)';
    }
    else
    {
        $cache_ttl = ($user_id == ANONYMOUS) ? 3600 : 0;
        $_sql = '(ban_userid = ' . $user_id;

    if ($user_email !== false)
    {
        $_sql .= " OR ban_email <> ''";
    }

    if ($user_ips !== false)
    {
        $_sql .= " OR ban_ip <> ''";
    }

        $_sql .= ')';

        $where_sql[] = $_sql;
    }

    $sql .= (sizeof($where_sql)) ? implode(' AND ', $where_sql) : '';
    $result = $db->sql_query($sql, $cache_ttl);

    $ban_triggered_by = 'user';
    while ($row = $db->sql_fetchrow($result))
    {
        if ($row['ban_end'] && $row['ban_end'] < time())
        {
            continue;
        }

        $ip_banned = false;
        if (!empty($row['ban_ip']))
        {
            if (!is_array($user_ips))
            {
                $ip_banned = preg_match('#^' . str_replace('\*', '.*?', preg_quote($row['ban_ip'], '#')) . '$#i', $user_ips);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach ($user_ips as $user_ip)
                {
                    if (preg_match('#^' . str_replace('\*', '.*?', preg_quote($row['ban_ip'], '#')) . '$#i', $user_ip))
                    {
                        $ip_banned = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if ((!empty($row['ban_userid']) && intval($row['ban_userid']) == $user_id) ||
            $ip_banned ||
            (!empty($row['ban_email']) && preg_match('#^' . str_replace('\*', '.*?', preg_quote($row['ban_email'], '#')) . '$#i', $user_email)))
        {
            if (!empty($row['ban_exclude']))
            {
                $banned = false;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                $banned = true;
                $ban_row = $row;

                if (!empty($row['ban_userid']) && intval($row['ban_userid']) == $user_id)
                {
                    $ban_triggered_by = 'user';
                }
                else if ($ip_banned)
                {
                    $ban_triggered_by = 'ip';
                }
                else
                {
                    $ban_triggered_by = 'email';
                }

                // don't break. Check if there is an exclude rule for this user
            }
        }
    }

    $db->sql_freeresult($result);

    if ($banned && !$return)
    {
        global $template;

        // if the session is empty we need to create a valid one...
        if (empty($this->session_id))
        {
            // this seems to be no longer needed? - #14971
            //$this->session_create(ANONYMOUS);
        }

        // initiate environment ... since it won't be set at this stage
        $this->setup();

        // logout the user, banned users are unable to use the normal 'logout' link
        if ($this->data['user_id'] != ANONYMOUS)
        {
            $this->session_kill();
        }

        // we show a login box here to allow founders accessing the board if banned by IP
        if (defined('IN_LOGIN') && $this->data['user_id'] == ANONYMOUS)
        {
            global $phpEx;

            $this->setup('ucp');
            $this->data['is_registered'] = $this->data['is_bot'] = false;

            // Set as a precaution to allow login_box() handling this case correctly as well as this function not being executed again.
            define('IN_CHECK_BAN', 1);

            login_box("index.$phpEx");

            // The false here is needed, else the user is able to circumvent the ban.
            $this->session_kill(false);
        }

        // ok, we catch the case of an empty session id for the anonymous user...
        // this can happen if the user is logging in, banned by username and the login_box() being called "again".
        if (empty($this->session_id) && defined('IN_CHECK_BAN'))
        {
            $this->session_create(ANONYMOUS);
        }

        // determine which message to output
        $till_date = ($ban_row['ban_end']) ? $this->format_date($ban_row['ban_end']) : '';
        $message = ($ban_row['ban_end']) ? 'BOARD_BAN_TIME' : 'BOARD_BAN_PERM';

        $message = sprintf($this->lang[$message], $till_date, '<a href="mailto:' . $config['board_contact'] . '">', '</a>');
        $message .= ($ban_row['ban_give_reason']) ? '<br /><br />' . sprintf($this->lang['BOARD_BAN_REASON'], $ban_row['ban_give_reason']) : '';
        $message .= '<br /><br /><em>' . $this->lang['BAN_TRIGGERED_BY_' . strtoupper($ban_triggered_by)] . '</em>';

        // to circumvent session_begin returning a valid value and the check_ban() not called on second page view, we kill the session again
        $this->session_kill(false);

        // a very special case... we are within the cron script which is not supposed to print out the ban message... show blank page
        if (defined('IN_CRON'))
        {
            garbage_collection();
            exit_handler();
            exit;
        }

        trigger_error($message);
    }

    return ($banned && $ban_row['ban_give_reason']) ? $ban_row['ban_give_reason'] : $banned;
}

// session stuff will not be needed as this occurs from a non-client session, but we need $user->setup it seems
if (empty($user->lang))
{
    $user->setup();
}

$user->add_lang('ucp');

// get variables
/* $data = request_var('data', '', true);
if (!isset($_GET['username']))
{ */
    $data = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = explode('&&', $data);

    $username = trim(htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\0"), array("\n", "\n", ''), $data[0]), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
    $password = trim(htmlspecialchars(str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\0"), array("\n", "\n", ''), $data[1]), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
/* }
else
{
    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];    
} */

// perform login from $auth. we don't want autologon, viewonline nor admin access for the session
$result = $auth->login($username, $password, false, false, false);
if ($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS)
{
    $userID = $user->data['user_id'];
    $user_id = array($userID);
    $canhave = get_profile_fields($user_id);

    if ($canhave[$userID]['can_play_expire']['value'] <= time())
    {
        $canhave[$userID]['can_play']['value'] = 1;
    }

    if ($canhave[$userID]['can_play']['value'] == 1 || $canhave[$userID]['can_play']['value'] == 0 || $canhave[$userID]['can_play']['value'] == "")
    {
        $canPlay = true;

        if (true || isGroup($user->data['user_id'])) 
        {
            $canPlay = true; 
            $keysql = "UPDATE phpbb_sessions SET session_onlineplay = 1, session_realip = '".htmlspecialchars(get_ip_address(), ENT_QUOTES)."' WHERE session_id = '".$user->session_id."';";
            $keyresult = $db->sql_query($keysql); 
            $db->sql_freeresult($keyresult);
        }
        else
        {
            $result['status'] = 'nope';  
            $result['error_msg'] = 'triobit is currently down for maintenance.';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $result['status'] = 'nope';  
        //$result['error_msg'] = 'User is not allowed to play'; 
        $result['error_msg'] = 'Online playing privileges revoked';

        if ($canhave[$userID]['can_play_reason']['value'])
        {
            $result['error_msg'] .= ' - ' . str_replace('#', '@', $canhave[$userID]['can_play_reason']['value']);
        }

        if ($canhave[$userID]['can_play_expire']['value'])
        {
            $result['error_msg'] .= ' (will expire in ' . duration($canhave[$userID]['can_play_expire']['value'] - time()) . ')';
        }
    }

    $banReason = check_ban($userID, '', '', 1);
    if ($banReason != "")
    {
        $result['status'] = 'nope';  
        $result['error_msg'] = 'User is banned';   
        $canPlay = false;
    } 
}

// start buffering (to allow kill)
ob_start();

// output the results
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? 'ok' : 'fail') . '#';
echo (($result['error_msg']) ? ((isset($user->lang[$result['error_msg']])) ? $user->lang[$result['error_msg']] : $result['error_msg']) : 'Success.') . '#';
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? $user->data['user_id'] : '1') . '#';
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? $user->data['username'] : 'Anonymous') . '#';
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? $user->data['user_email'] : 'anonymous@example.com') . '#';
echo (($result['status'] == LOGIN_SUCCESS) ? $user->session_id : '0') . '#';

//Deleted, used for login verify now
// kill the session
if (!$canPlay)
{
    $user->session_kill(false);
}

// and flush the contents
ob_end_flush();
exit;

function format_duration($seconds) {
    $periods = array(
        'centuries' => 3155692600,
        'decades' => 315569260,
        'years' => 31556926,
        'months' => 2629743,
        'weeks' => 604800,
        'days' => 86400,
        'hours' => 3600,
        'minutes' => 60,
        'seconds' => 1
    );

    $durations = array();

    foreach ($periods as $period => $seconds_in_period) {
        if ($seconds >= $seconds_in_period) {
            $durations[$period] = floor($seconds / $seconds_in_period);
            $seconds -= $durations[$period] * $seconds_in_period;
        }
    }

    return $durations;
}

function duration($seconds) {
    $data = format_duration($seconds);
    $data2 = array();

    foreach ($data as $unit => $amount)
    {
        $data2[] = $amount . ' ' . $unit;
    }

    return implode(', ', $data2);
}
```